# How to export variables when variables have value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to exports token variable but if user not authenticate token is undefined if user authenticate success token will have value

i try this but not work, token variable still undefined in another file

code file sent token variable

```
if (token != undefined){
    module.exports.token = token;
}
```

code file receive token variable

```
const auth = require('../../../../dashboard/module/auth');
console.log(auth.token);
```

It seems to ignore the condition and immediately send the token undefined variable to another file.

Comment: Remember that `!=` is rarely good enough. Use `===` and `!==` unless you _absolutely need_ coercion. Which you almost never do. That said, ask yourself what happens when token _is_ `undefined`. What behaviour would you _expect_ to see, and what are you currently seeing happen?

Comment: "*if user authenticate success token will have value*" - please post the code that does that.

Comment: What's the point of `if (token != undefined){`? Just always export the variable (value), with the respective value that it has. "*It seems to ignore the condition and immediately send the token undefined variable to another file.*" makes it sound like you expected that code to make something wait until it has a value?

Answer (score 0):

#### Can you be sure that it really *has* exported?

If it did not export, what would you expect `auth.token` to be?

To test this possibility, try a couple of things:

```
if (token != undefined){
    module.exports.token = token;
    module.exports.test1 = "this is a test";
}
```

and in your receiving code:

```
const auth = require('../../../../dashboard/module/auth');
console.log("token:",auth.token);
console.log("test1:",auth.test1);
console.log("test2:",auth.test2);
```

#### If it really *is* exporting, you should see this:

- undefined
- "this is a test"
- undefined

#### But if it is *not* exporting, you should see this:

- undefined
- undefined
- undefined

#### Mechanism

From the result of the above test, you should be able to see the *reason* for the `undefined` in your original code